# problema con parseint java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:

Tags: android, string, integer

Hola gracias de antemano por atender mi problema.
Estoy tratando de hacer una simple resta en android studio de 2 valores que se encuentran en Edittext pero no me funciona valueOf y el parseint. me devuelve un error. Estuve buscando y no pude encontrar una solución que funcione.

me pueden decir que estoy haciendo mal?

### Codigo

```
public void resta(){



    int puntosInt1=Integer.valueOf(puntosVal.getText().toString().trim());
    int puntosProductoIn1 = Integer.valueOf(punto_descuento.getText().toString().trim());


    int descuentoFinal1 = puntosInt1 + puntosProductoIn1;

    puntosPrin.setText(descuentoFinal1);

}

}
```

---

[image: Error]

Comment: En realidad tienes 2 problemas, uno es el convertir un valor que no es númerico a Int y el otro es tratar de agregar un valor númerico a tu TextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema en realidad es a la hora de ponerle el texto al textview,

```
   puntosPrin.setText(descuentoFinal1);
```

Estas intentando colocar un entero como texto, debes  hacer un cast a texto.

```
   puntosPrin.setText(String.valueOf(descuentoFinal1));
```

Comment: Funciona, muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

En realidad tienes 2 problemas:

**El primero el cual esta especificado en el LogCat, el cual se produce al convertir un valor que no es númerico a Integer mediante `Integer.valueOf()`**.

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:

```
int puntosInt1=Integer.valueOf(puntosVal.getText().toString().trim());
int puntosProductoIn1 = Integer.valueOf(punto_descuento.getText().toString().trim());
```

Para resolver este problema puedes hacer uso del siguiente método, el cual al detectar un error tratando de convertir un valor no númerico o null, entrega un valor predeterminado 0 ( lo puedes cambiar) :

```
public static int checkNumerico(String valor) {
    int resultado = 0; //Valor predeterminado en caso de error.
    if(valor!=null){
       valor = valor.trim();
    }else{
        return resultado;
    }
    try {           
        resultado = Integer.valueOf(valor);            
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Lo usarías de esta forma:

```
   int puntosInt1=Integer.valueOf(checkNumerico(puntosVal.getText().toString()));
   int puntosProductoIn1 = Integer.valueOf(checkNumerico(punto_descuento.getText().toString()();
```

---

**El segundo problema se produce al usar el método [setText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)) definiendo como parámetro un valor tipo int, ya que supondrá que estas definiendo un id de recurso**, en este caso debes convertir el valor a String, lo puedes realizar de varias formas.

Concatendo una cadena vacia:

```
puntosPrin.setText(""+descuentoFinal1);
```

Usando el método `String.valueOf()`:

```
puntosPrin.setText(String.valueOf(descuentoFinal1));
```